# c++ Got a segmentation fault - Does c++ autofree objects?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I wonder about my Class in a c++ file. I do have a class named "node" and one named "edge". In this class node is a method like this:

```
Edge calculateEdgeTo(Node&);
```

And then a main file with the following operations:

```
Node* n1 = new Node(...);
Node* n2 = new Node(...);

delete n1;
delete n2;
```

and this works.. but if I:

```
Node* n1 = new Node(...);
Node* n2 = new Node(...);

Edge e = n1->calculateEdgeTo(*n2);

delete n1;
delete n2;
```

I got a segmentation fault (I think n1 is already freed). It also doesn't work, if I try to perform an other operation on n1... always a segmentation fault.

EDIT:

here is the code of the function:

```
Edge Node::calculateEdgeTo(Node& node){
    return new Edge((*this), (*this));
}
```

and the constructor of edge:

```
Edge::Edge(const Node& src, const Node& tar){
    this->src = &src;
    this->tar = &tar;
}
```

while src and tar are pointer on nodes.

END OF EDIT.

Why is n1 freed from the system?? How can I force it not to do this?

Alex

Comment: Really? You expect us to *guess* what `calculateEdgeTo` does and answer your question based on the guess? How do you think the world works?

Comment: It's probably a case of failing to write correct copy constructors and assignment operators for your Node class. Did you write these?

Comment: C++ does not auto-free objects, and a segmentation fault is not likely to be related to having not freed your own allocation.

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to figure out where your code is crashing?

Comment: From that it seems, calculateEdgeTo simply has bug which causes it to crash, nothing to do with deleting... Or Node constructor has bug, leaving the object in bad state (like null or uninitialized pointers).

Comment: Your assumptions on the problem are wrong. You really need to be more specific about your class implementation (constructors, `calculateEdgeTo`...) or it's really hard to help you.

Comment: @alexvii Oh well, question closed. If you can't figure it out please post again, but this time post enough code to allow someone to answer the question.

Comment: ok.. i looked again at the function and shrinked it so it just does: return new Edge((*this), (*this)); because a edge has 2 node points as fields

Comment: @alexvii. Still can't see the problem from the code posted. You really should post complete programs. Still I've voted to reopen, someone else might have an idea. If you include a complete program with this bug, then you would have more chance of getting the question re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

No, C++ does not "autofree" objects. They are only deleted when you call `delete` on them.

Some possible reasons that your code is crashing might be:

- Your `calculateEdgeTo` function must be doing something wrong, which is producing your segfault, not the objects being freed.
- When you dereference `n2` by doing `*n2` and then passing that to `calculateEdgeTo`, you have to be sure that the correct data from `n2` is being copied into the `Node` being used within the `calculateEdgeTo` function. You need to write copy constructors to ensure that this works.

Comment: It might not be doing anything wrong in itself. It might be the lack of a proper Node copy constructor. But no way to tell from the code posted.

Comment: @john Ah, you're right. I didn't see that `n2` was dereferences before it was passed in.